# Trello API: the updateCard:idList filter doesn't return any cards

Tags: api, trello

Using the Trello API, "filter=updateCard:idList" doesn't seem to work? If I leave the ":idList" off, it returns my cards. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's been my experience that their system only generates a generic updateCard action when moving a card.  I have played with it quite a bit in order to flesh out its properties for [my .Net wrapper](https://nuget.org/packages/Manatee.Trello/), and can't seem to determine how to generate that specific action.

Given that, I'd say that the filter is working properly, but the specific action type is not being applied to any actions, therefore yielding no results.